# Casing text depending on punctuation

Tags: python, text, formatting, state-machine

Which would be the most efficient way to change a text to it's proper case depending on punctuation marks and fix formatting (whitespace, etc)?

```
the qUiCk BROWN fox:: jumped. over , the lazy    dog.
```

Desired result:

```
The quick brown fox: jumped. Over, the lazy dog.
```

Comment: What should you do about proper nouns? Say for example `"qUick BROWN"` was `"oReO DISNEY orlando florida herman melville"`. What should be capitalised? Whatever you write is going to be incomplete. Are you processing a file at a time? Do you need to track whether sentences continue over multiple lines?

Comment: Only words after a period should be capitalized, not processing files, and keeping track of sentences that continue over multiple lines

Comment: @Siddharth I don't get it either! :)

Comment: I did my part, to keep this community as good as your question. I hope who ever did a -ve, reads these comments and feels guilty about it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged your question "regex" but I do not recommend the use of regular expressions to try to solve this.  This is best handled with a simple state machine.

Here is a simple state machine adequate to handle your example.  If you try it on other text you will likely find cases it doesn't handle; I hope that you will find its design clear, and you will have no trouble modifying it to suit your purpose.

```
import string

s = "the qUiCk BROWN fox:: jumped. over , the lazy    dog."
s_correct = "The quick brown fox: jumped. Over, the lazy dog."


def chars_from_lines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        for ch in line:
            yield ch

start, in_sentence, saw_space = range(3)

punct = set(string.punctuation)
punct_non_repeat = punct - set(['.', '-'])
end_sentence_chars = set(['.', '!', '?'])

def edit_sentences(seq):
    state = start
    ch_punct_last = None

    for ch in seq:
        ch = ch.lower()

        if ch == ch_punct_last:
            # Don't pass repeated punctuation.
            continue
        elif ch in punct_non_repeat:
            ch_punct_last = ch
        else:
            # Not punctuation to worry about, so forget the last.
            ch_punct_last = None

        if state == start and ch.isspace():
            continue
        elif state == start:
            state = in_sentence
            yield ch.upper()

        elif state == in_sentence and ch in end_sentence_chars:
            state = start
            yield ch
            yield ' '
        elif state == in_sentence and not ch.isspace():
            yield ch
        elif state == in_sentence and ch.isspace():
            state = saw_space
            continue

        elif state == saw_space and ch.isspace():
            # stay in state saw_space
            continue
        elif state == saw_space and ch in punct:
            # stay in state saw_space
            yield ch
        elif state == saw_space and ch.isalnum():
            state = in_sentence
            yield ' '
            yield ch

#with open("input.txt") as f:
#    s_result = ''.join(ch for ch in edit_sentences(chars_from_lines(f)))

s_result = ''.join(ch for ch in edit_sentences(s))

print(s_result)
print(s_correct)
```

Comment: +1, state machines are a good approach to a number of problems, and well worth keeping in the mental toolkit.

Comment: thanks! interesting stuff here :)

Comment: I didn't put in any comments to explain it, but the check for punctuation allows periods and dashes to repeat... for ellipses (like "repeat...") and for long dashes--like the ones to the left of "like".

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `line` is the input string. The following should do something pretty close to what you want. Note that newlines (and other whitespace) will be turned into single spaces.

```
import string    # used to check if a character is a letter
#assume we start with a letter and not, for instance, a quotation mark
assert line[0] in string.letters
line = line.capitalize()
duplPunct = [] #list of indices of duplicate punctuation
prev = line[0]
for i in range(len(line))[1:]:
    if line[i] == prev and prev not in string.letters:
        duplPunct.append(i)
    prev = line[i]
while len(duplPunct):
    i = duplPunct.pop()    #returns last index needing deletion
    line = line[:i]+line[i+1:]
words = line.split() #removes all whitespace
floatingchar = []  #list of indices of words containing only a single invalid character
for i in range(len(words))[1:]:
    word = words[i]
    if len(word) == 1 and word not in 'ai':
        #assume single-character 'words' should be part of previous word
        floatingchar.append(i)
while len(floatingchar):
    i = floatingchar.pop()
    words[i-1] = words[i-1]+words[i]
    del words[i]
needCaps = [] #list of indices of words requiring capitalization
for i in range(len(words))[:-1]:
    if words[i][-1] in '.!?':
        needCaps.append(i+1)
while len(needCaps):
    i = needCaps.pop()
    words[i] = words[i].capitalize()
line = ' '.join(words)
```